# How to set z-index and Autoclose for bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: html, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular8, z-index

The zIndexOffset which i gave in bsConfig is not working. Also i need to enable autoclose on scroll...
Would anyone help me figure how to do it?

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
this.bsConfig = Object.assign(
      {},
      {
        containerClass: this.datepickerColorTheme,
        zIndexOffset: -3,
        dateInputFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        showWeekNumbers: false
      }
    );
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
            <input id="OfficialDob" placeholder="Date of Birth" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
              formControlName="OfficialDob" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks